# How to generate the name of the index when scripting using SMO

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-schema, smo

I'm currently scripting my entire database using SMO, it's working fine. The only problem is when I recreate the database from the script and do a Sql Delta comparison the only thing that's different is the name of the primary keys.

When I look at the script that is generated it doesn't actually provide a name of the key and so I guess SQL Server just randomly assigns one.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get SMO to include the name of the primary key in the script?

If not I suppose I'll stop using SMO for the keys and read them manually and produce the script for keys myself.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, SMO appears to treat indexes and constraints as synonymous - you should be able to get the name of PKs by checking the table.indexes collection for the [name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.index.name.aspx) of the index with [IndexKeyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.index.indexkeytype.aspx) of [DriPrimaryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.indexkeytype.aspx).